# Why do spaceships in Star Wars have wings?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

Many of the spaceships in *Star Wars*, e.g. X-wings, have wings as part of their design. If there's no air resistance in space, why would wings be at all beneficial? Wouldn't it be better to have a small, compact shape to a make a star fighter easier to cram through small spaces?

Comment: Many of these ships are also designed to fly inside an atmosphere, ie they are multipurpose, hence the more complicated design.

Comment: Because in Star Wars, space has structure called Ether. Space planes like the X-wing fly through it like a plane flies through air

Comment: Because the designers think wings look cool. Just like spoilers on your average consumer car.

Comment: *"Set attack wings to "**Sell Toys!"** position"*

Comment: LOL valorum's post....very funny...

Comment: @MrInfinity - Stolen from the MST3K boys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Watsonian

1. Heat dispersion. Having extended ‘foils’ (the structures you refer to as wings, at least on X-wings, are called S-foils) provides greater heat dispersion, both by surface area, and by distancing the heat-producing cannons from the cockpit. In Legends canon, TIE fighter radiator panels serve the same purpose.
2. Stabilization. Allegedly, the s-foils provide in-atmo stabilization, and damage to them is frequently shown to cause a loss of atmospheric flight control. This suggests they are used for in-atmo stabilization. Based on the fact that fast-moving helicopters IRL have wing stubs partly for this purpose, it’s not too outlandish.
3. Greater weapon carrying capacity. See again helicopters, like the Russian Mi-24 
   [image]
   carry additional weapons on their wing stubs, just as X-wings do. Fitting those cannons under the protected fuselage will require a bulkier body, which presumably is undesirable.

## Doylist

They look cool.

Answer (score 13):

You might as well ask this of most spaceship designs in any science fiction work, it's not specific to *Star Wars* at all. However, there is a very simple reason and one you have overlooked. Whilst *Star Wars* as a whole plays with physics, most spaceships do have to fly in a planet's atmosphere. We see them going in and out of planets all the time and even flying and fighting inside of them. For example, at the Battle of Takonda in *The Force Awakens* we see X-wings and TIE Fighters in the atmosphere fighting. Wings are beneficial here.

[image: X-wings flying over a lake]

Comment: An X-wing's wings are not shaped to generate lift, and a double wing design like this creates a lot of drag that would be bad for a conventional aircraft. The wings are not beneficial from a classical flying machine point of view. And a Tie-fighter's wings are vertically orientated. Nice picture though...

Comment: @Jontia Sure the actual out of universe reason is because it makes them more recognisable. The more drag is handwaved away with _Star Wars_ physics... I don't know enough on this sort of thing though to comment properly myself.

Comment: Remember too: Lucas (and his army of writers) could get away with this because it's another galaxy far away from ours and long before ours. Thus their physics may be completely different from ours. This gave Lucas and his writers that ultimate freedom.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan How many billions of years does it take to change physics?

Comment: @ZevSpitz [quite a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-variation_of_fundamental_constants)

Comment: My point is: different galaxy from ours, so different physics can apply. This isn’t the Milky Way. We can’t assume our laws of physics upon the SW galaxy.

Comment: Yeah, you can actually.  That is kind of the whole point of them.  Different atmospheres/environments might change how things operate somewhat on a world by world basis but the laws of physics aren't going to be different.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan By that logic nothing in the *Star Wars* universe can be explained by us at all, rendering all such questions unanswerable and impossible to investigate.

Comment: Ok......keyword......fiction.

Answer (score 10):

Another factor is weapon placement. Wings or similar structures are perfect spots to put the ships weaponry to allow it to concentrate heavy firepower on the front.

A compact fighter simply doesn't have the width to mount more than 1-2 guns in most universes (there are of course sci-fi universes where weapons don't take up a lot of space), so having another 2-4 guns on the wings allows the fighter to bring more firepower to bear while keeping its own hitbox as small as possible.

You often see capital ships not having wings, as those use flexible turrets, while star fighter type ships use fixed gun emplacements with a high amount of manouverability.

Comment: _Wings or similar structures are perfect spots to put the ships weaponry_ - Actually, experience with the P-38 in WWII shows that nose mounted guns are ideal because they shoot straight rather than triangulated.  But wings do let you carry _more_ guns.

Comment: @gowenfawr Well, if you'd quoted the other half of the sentence: "to allow it to concentrate heavy firepower on the front", i.e. put a lot of guns on the ship, which is also the point of the rest of the answer. Also in a sci-fi universe, you can reasonably allow a targetting system, which nullifies the natural advantage of shooting straight.

Comment: @gowenfawr At least in Legends, X-wing cannons could be deliberately set to have one of a number of ‘converge’ points at a specific distance directly in front of the ship, thus mostly negating the advantage of shooting straight.

Comment: @Dulkan I'm not sure you can reasonably allow a competent targeting system in a cinematic universe founded upon the singular act of a farmboy listening to the voices in his head and turning *off* the targeting computer to score a decisive hit.

Comment: @gowenfawr My point was general, not specific to Star Wars, as this question may arise in a multitude of sci-fi universes

Answer (score 10):

Ships in the Star Wars universe travel through a property known as "ether" which acts as a dragging force. This explains a considerable number of issues including why ships have a top speed, how explosions can be heard in space, why there's no overt worries about relativistic effects, why ships need to burn fuel constantly to maintain their speed, how tight turns are made and **why X-Wings have actual wings**

Pablo Hidalgo (Head of the Lucasfilm's Star Wars Story Group) spoke to this in a recent [tweet](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/947547302104776704) (now deleted)

> **PH:** *If you need to, you could say the interstellar medium in Star Wars does have an ether, which would explain such pulpy things as
> sound, concussion rings, visible drag, and such odd tech callouts as
> "an etheric rudder" from Heir to the Empire. Only if you ⋆really⋆ need
> to, though.*
>
> *Like if it helps you sleep at night and whatnot.*

Comment: That tweet link gives me a 404.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Pablo Hidalgo regularly deletes his tweets older than a few months. It's annoying but I like to leave the links in in case someone is trying to manage an archive

Comment: Fair enough, on that note though aren't Pablo's tweets semi-canon so to speak? (Upvoted anyway just thought I'd seen something along those lines before).

Comment: And [archived link](http://web.archive.org/web/20171231202140/https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/947547302104776704) for proof.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - He certainly claims they aren't. I think it's mostly so people won't keep bugging him

Comment: Makes sense, I couldn't remember the exact wording though.

Comment: This is a bad answer imho. Outside of a deleted tweet, this is literally never referenced in canon that I know of, and that tweet is hardly an endorsement of the concept. “If you need to, you can say...” is, I’d argue, almost a *refutation* of this as canon.

Comment: @DanielB the tweet is essentially saying that there is no in-universe cannon reason, or Pablo Hidalgo would have stated that. But if there was a reason, this would probably be it. A rephrasing would help this answer I think.

Comment: @DanielB - The issue is that ether is taken as such a constant in Star Wars that it's never mentioned. But it's there nonetheless.

Comment: @Valorum It feels irresponsible to state “Ships in the Star Wars universe travel through a property known as "ether" which acts as a dragging force” with such authority without presenting evidence. It being a convenient explanation for several idiosyncrasies does not make it true.

Comment: @DanielB - Pablo Hidalgo is about as close an authority as you can get on the subject without actually being George Lucas

Comment: “If you need to, you can-“ and “if it helps you sleep at night” are, if anything, confirmations that this theory is *wrong* / not canon, and should only be considered true if it brings you some arbitrary comfort.

Comment: @DanielB - What he's saying is that as far as he's concerned, these are simply elements of the fantasy setting and, in his opinion, not in need of explanation... **but that here's the explanation if you're sad enough to care**.

Comment: I’d argue that he’s saying “here’s *an* explanation, not *the* explanation. Either way, I have too much respect for you and the work you do on this site to argue the point more. :p

Answer (score 1):

These are both out-of-universe answers, but 1. The Rule of Cool, and 2. SW is a fantasy with slight sci-fi tropes, so it often doesn't conform to standard space rules. As other answers have mentioned, this applies to sound in space and also things like the bombers losing speed and falling in The Last Jedi. Why did that happen? Cause SW is a fantasy and George Lucas based his dogfights around WWII dogfights.